# Ember-cli nested model array using {{each}} helper re-renders whole list when adding to Ember data store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, htmlbars

I have a route that loads a dashboard

```
// routes/dashboard/index.js
...
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('dashboard', params.dashboard_id);
  }
...
```

The dashboard model contains a hasMany relationship to the widget model

```
// models/dashboard.js
...
DS.Model.extend({
  widgets: hasMany('widget', {async: true})
...
```

The widget model contains a belongsTo relationship to the dashboard model

```
// models/widget.js
...
DS.Model.extend({
  dashboard: belongsTo('dashboard', {async: true})
...
```

The dashboard.index template renders the widgets using the {{each}} helper

```
// templates/dashboard/index.js
...
{{#each model.widgets as |widget|}}
  {{widget config="widget"}}
{{/each}}
...
```

The user can add a widget to their dashboard

```
// routes/dashboard/index.js
...
actions: {
  addWidget: function() {
    this.store.createRecord('widget', {
      dashboard: this.modelFor('dashboard.index')
      ...
    });
  }
}
```

Although this works, when the new widget is created, ALL widgets are re-rendered.

Some things of note:
- I have not implemented a View or Controller.
- If I change the implementation to return just a collection of widgets, causing ember-cli to create an ArrayController rather than an ObjectController, the each loop does not re-render (excellent). However, dashboards have more than one child array that needs to be rendered, and so I cannot take this approach.
- Despite efforts to implement the object controller and create my own array controllers, I cannot get the same functionality here.

Any suggestions of how I can add widgets without all widgets re-rendering?

Comment: After a bit more investigation, it appears that this problem only occurs when the relationship is {async: true}. I don't know why async being true on the relationship would cause the each helper to re-render all items, whereas a none async relationship works...

Comment: Link to github issue: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3093